# Extract in variable value of screen resize

Tags: jquery, resize, size, screen

I try get out of function window resize the value of size when people resize the window , the first problem it´s get this value out of function as i tell until

```
    jQuery(window).resize(function() 
    {
    var height = jQuery(window).height();
    var width = jQuery(window).width();
alert(""+width);
    });
```

If i put one alert inside function get the value of height and width , the problem it´s if i want put alert out of function or resize , never get value , i want get this because i have some function and need inactive these if size of screen it´s under of 500 px

**NO WORKS NEVER**

```
        jQuery(window).resize(function() 
        {
        var height = jQuery(window).height();
        var width = jQuery(window).width();

        });

alert(""+width);
```

I hope understand this , thank´s for the help , the best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor your code so that global variables are not necessary, but to do it like you're currently trying:

```
var height, width;

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    height = jQuery(window).height();
    width = jQuery(window).width();
});

alert(width);
```

Declaring the variables outside all functions makes them globally accessible.

Comment: I try this but no work me : var w;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(window).resize(function() 
{
 
 
h=jQuery(window).height();  
w=jQuery(window).width(); 

//alert(""+w);

});
});



alert(""+w);

Comment: Yeah, it wont work directly as such, since the alert will fire before the window has been resized. But using the width variable anywhere after a resize will work, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w1k3bbes/